# Fix button for a div in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a `div` and a `button` which need to be fixed. My HTML code is as follows:

```
<div id="MyMainContent" style="width:100%;float:left">
    <div style="width:70%; float:left;">MyContent</div>
    <div style="width:28%; float:left;left: 67%; position: fixed;">
        <asp:Button ID="ReplyButton" runat="server" Text="Reply" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The button is fixed for whole page. When I scroll down the page it is for the Page. I want the button to be fixed for a div `MyMainContent` only.

I have tried this css in `MyMainContent`

```
style="width:100%;float:left;position:relative"
```

but it is showing the same result.
  Is there a solution to do so? any help or link are surely appretiated.

Comment: fixed positioned elements will be positioned relative to the window. it won't be scrolled with the page. it is not clear what you want to achieve from the question.

Comment: A http://jsfiddle.net showing the problem would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Fixed positioned elements will be positioned relative to the window. it won't be scrolled with the page.

If you want it to be positioned relative to a div,

Put the button inside `MyMainContent` and position it absolutely relative to the `MyMainContent`.

In other words give `position:relative` to `MyMainContent` and apply `position:absolute` for the button and position it inside the div using `top right bottom left` properties.

Absolute positioned element will be positioned relative to the first parent having a position other than static.

Comment: I want the button should be fixed

Comment: `I want the button to be fixed for a div MyMainContent only.` that sounds like you want the button positioned inside the div? what is it that you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want the button to be fixed for the div `MyMainContent` only not for the whole page.